# Is there anything wrong in this function of WordPress to apply custom scrips and style to the theme?

Tags: wordpress

This is function which i am adding in functions.php but it is not working. Is there anything wrong in this code?

```
    function custom_scripts_css_with_jquery()
{

    //wp_register_script( 'Bootstrap_min_js','//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js');
    wp_register_script( 'select2jquery', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js');
    wp_register_style( 'select2mincss', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css');

    // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the style:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'select2jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'select2mincss' );
    //wp_enqueue_script( 'Bootstrap_min_js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts_css_with_jquery' );
```

Answer (score 0):

use beloe function

```
     function custom_scripts_css_with_jquery()
{
    // Deregister the included library
    //wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );

    // Register the library again from Google's CDN
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js', array(), null, false );
    wp_register_script( 'select2jquery', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js', array(), null, false );
    // Register the style like this for a theme:
    wp_register_style( 'select2mincss', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css', array(), '4.0.3', 'all' );

    // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the style:
    wp_enqueue_style( 'select2mincss' );


}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts_css_with_jquery' );
```

Comment: I tried that with updated code which is in the updated question now. But it is still not working @Shital Marakana